# Change TextBox contents on state change

Tags: sketchflow

When using the Sketchflow designer is it possible to have the content of a TextBox change when moving between states. For example if i have a TextBox containing the text "Foo" in state A, is it possible to have that same TextBox display "Bar" in state B. This can probably be done in code pretty easily but i want to know if it can be done in Blend. So far changes that i make to text in a specific state are replicated across all states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If animating the text isn't working you could always show/hide different text elements to simulate the change you are looking for.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, created 2 TextBoxes then swapped visibility in the different states. Appears that you can't obviously change the text property using the Blend IDE. There are a few ways to do it in code by attaching to the CurrentStateChanged event in VisualStateGroup see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653394/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653394/)